# How can I make image always stay side to side on resize not crop

Tags: html, css

do you know how can I make image not crop but also not strech. I tried using object-fit cover, but it streches, it loses height, what I want to achieve is something like this, using either images, or maybe clippath
[image]

What I tried so far:

```css
.bar {
        background-image: url("../../img/home/bar-bottom.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 174.55px;
 

    }
    
    .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bottom-shape-img">
<img src="/static/media/bottom-shape.fc5ce966aeea4c482f4f5df0d5beec8c.svg" alt="BottomShapeImg"></div>
<div class="bar">
</div>
</div>
```

When I resize it goes like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an ID and on css sheet give that id an width of 100%

```css
#test {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <img src="image.png" alt="BottomShapeImg" id="test">
```